# Orbits and alternating groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

> $A_4$ acts on a strip of 4 square tiles by exchanging them. The tiles are coloured with k-colours allowing repetitions. How many orbits of the action are there?

So I assumed that $A_4$ means an alternating group. I don't understand how alternating groups work and due to the question being a worded problem, how the set $X$ is structured.

Comment: What is the relevance of the colours? What do you mean by the set $x$?

Comment: For $A_4$ try https://www.math.uci.edu/~ndonalds/math120a/a4.pdf

Comment: @MartinRattigan well there is a set of four squares that can have k different colours is my interpretation so i think that means the tiles represent a set with 4 elements where there are k different values for the elements.

Comment: But that doesn't say how the colours relate to the group actions. Are only tiles with the same colours exchanged?

Comment: @MartinRattigan too be honest im not 100% sure. the wording of the problem is not the best... thats why i posted the question to see if anyone else had any idea to how to interpret it.

Comment: Well, beats me. How many orbits of *which* action for instance? I should request clarification if possible.

Comment: @Martin Suppose the colors are red, green, blue. Then the permutation $(12)(34)$ for instance would send $\rm RGBR$ to $\rm GRRB$. (The tiles are colored, and the permutation, well, permutes them.) The set on which $A_4$ acts is the presumably set of all configurations of $4$ tiles in a row with colors drawn from a palette of $k$ colors.

Comment: @arctic tern An interesting hypothesis, but if I understand group actions correctly the permutation $(12)(34)$ could also leave $RGBR$ as $RGBR$ or send it to $RBGR$ or ... depending on the particular way $A_4$ acts on the tiles and hence the set of colour sequences. And by an action I  would understand the mapping corresponding to a particular element of $A_4$, so which one is meant? Or is the number required the total for all elements of $A_4$ and all possible group actions? How are you supposed to tell from the question?

Comment: @MartinRattigan $A_4$ permutes $4$ things and the tiles are $4$ things, so of course $A_4$ permutes the tiles. Coloring problems are standard textbook exercises for group actions and combinatorics.

Comment: @arctic tern - $A_4$ *can be* represented as a permutation group on 4 objects, but from the definitions of group action I've read (e.g.http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GroupAction.html or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action) this needn't translate directly to  permutations of the set acted on via a 1-1 correspondence of 4 objects in such a representation to 4 objects in the set acted on.  contd...

Comment: For instance if $H$ is the subgroup generated by double cycles in $A_4$ (represented as even permutations on 4 objects)  then $A_4$ could act on the tiles by leaving the first tile fixed and making each element act as a permutation of the remaining three tiles according to which coset of $H$ it is in. The question doesn't state which group action is intended.

Comment: @MartinRattigan When there is a universally understood and agreed upon, standard, default assumption of which group action is intended, there is no need to explicitly state it. In addition to permutation groups this happens with e.g. homeomorphism groups, diffeomorphism groups, isometry groups, general linear groups, and in general the symmetry group of any mathematical object (meaning the automorphism group of an object in any concrete category). If a group is literally *defined* in terms of a certain group action, that group action will be the intended one unless otherwise stated.

Comment: @arctic tern - obviously *not quite* universally understood :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Four colored tiles may be formalized as a $4$-tuple $(c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4)$ with $c_i$ a color drawn from a palette of $k$ colors, or equivalently a number between $1$ and $k$. This may in turn be viewed as a function $\{1,2,3,4\}\to \{1,\cdots,k\}$ on which $A_4$ acts by $(\sigma\cdot f)(x)=f(\sigma^{-1}x)$.

You could apply [Polya's enumeration theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem), or work it out by hand. If you want to do it by hand, split into cases according to the multiplicities the colors. (E.g. four distinct colors, two colors on two tiles each, etc.)

Comment: But how would I fit this to this particular problem where I think the tiles are not behaving like the common 'bracelet' example problem when it comes to Polya's enumeration theorem? All the examples I've found using this theorem include symmetries.

Comment: @jdminer I don't see what the issue is. The only thing important about the symmetries is that they were group actions. Here you have a group action. Same thing. Are you saying you have familiarity with Polya's enumeration theorem? If so, then just use the theorem. There's nothing stopping you.

Comment: I don't have familiarity with it, I'm new to group theory in general so I'm probably just confused on how it's used :/

Comment: @jdminer Okay, if you're not familiar with Polya's enumeration theorem (which is weird because you knew the bracelet problems were common), then you can do this by hand. As I said, split into cases according to multiplicities of the colors.

Comment: Oh i tried doing some research on it when you mentioned it. I'll see how i do with that method :)